# Granting BigQuery permissions for a specific running project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

We're using BigQuery in a big team.

When I grant access for a dataset to a user, that user can query this dataset using a different project. (Project chosen on top)
In that case, I can't see the users query history on this dataset, since it's run using another project.

Let's say I grant access to an external consultant. That consultant can query all my data using another project, so I can't detect which queries that consultant ran.

So in short, is it possible to see all the queries from all the projects accessing to a specific table / dataset in BQ?
Or another solution, is it possible to limit the projects that can access a dataset?

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819163), the tutorial in the answer might help to see who accessed your resources

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue by following the previous comment ?

Comment: No, I think it's a huge security issue on Google side. The logs don't show the project the data is queried from.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen Its better to contact [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) so they can inspect the issue more specifically.Whether its happening only in your case or its the same for everyone that would be clear then.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen One more thing if you do not have any support plan you can create a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) also