# Can I audit access to a BigQuery dataset shared with external users?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm making a BigQuery dataset available to specific external users (meaning, they run their queries in the context of a private project) through dataset sharing. Is there any way to collect basic metrics regarding the use of the dataset, such as - which tables are being accessed?

Answer (score 2):

This is doable through [Google BigQuery audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs). [This tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-3-simple-ways-to-audit-and-monitor-your-dabatase-1cf09027f0de) provides step-by-step instructions for how to save the logs in a BQ dataset and query it for analysis.